# fbx export to unity missing textures

Tags: export, unity, .fbx

But I am a second day newb in blender.

When i export the asset into unity through fbx the character is just white. No textures or anything. Same with mixamo as well. I am starting to think fbx is not the answer.

However, blender is so complex that I cannot find exactly what I am looking for in the web.

Any quick pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you kindly.

Comment: No, it is not a dumb question. Actually it is a question that gets asked often, so it has been answered many times. Use the search box at the top of the page.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=Fbx+textures

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the right direction. You're a legend